# Не правильно работает функция

Tags: python, tkinter

После ввода текста в поле и нажатия Enter, введенный текст должен отобразится в метке.Только у меня не вышло

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()

def bar(event):
    text.configure(text='')
    lab['text'] = tex['text']


tex=Text(root,height=5,width=10)
tex.pack()

lab=Label(root,text='')
lab.pack()

lab.bind('<Return>',bar)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Вы enter нажимаете в текстовом поле, а реакцию на событие привязываете к метке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import*


def bar(event):
    lab['text'] = tex.get("1.0", END)


root = Tk()
tex = Text(root, height=5, width=10)
tex.pack()

lab = Label(root, text='')
lab.pack()

tex.bind('<Return>', bar)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо но не работает

Comment: @A.Kross как понять не работает ошибку выдает или что? Просто при использовании данного кода у меня все предельно нормально работает как видно на примере

Comment: Ошибочка вышла. Работает. Звеняйте